# ec2auth is not working when called from another script

Tags: php, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to automate white list of IP in AWS firewall using ec2auth by making it a link that on clicks obtains the IP from a php file and calls on a bash script. The bash script checks if this person is suppose to have access then the calls another bash script which does the firewall IP update.

BASH1

```
if [ "$ACCESS" = "allowed" ]
   then echo -n "Updating access... "
        BASH2 "$newIP"

fi
```

BASH2

```
IP="$1"
echo -n "Adding new IP... "
addResult="$(ec2auth group -P tcp -p 3389 -s "$IP"/32)"
```

But doing so I am getting an error

```
addResult is: +-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|    Code     |                           Message                            |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| AuthFailure | AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But if I run BASH2 from the terminal it works fine. Any one know what is wrong.

Comment: What is the variable `IP` in BASH2? Is it set to the argument passed to the script somewhere, e.g., `IP=$1`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work

BASH1

```
if [ "$ACCESS" = "allowed" ]
   then echo -n "Updating access... "
    sudo /fullpath/BASH2 "$newIP"

fi
```

and part of my sudoers file

```
# User privilege specification
www-data        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /fullpath/BASH1, /fullpath/BASH2
```

Hope it helps some one else. If you why this works please let me know. Thanks